# A number off or a number of?

Tags: grammar, phrases, differences

I am reading some technical documents and there is a list of items that make up the product. Throughout the document where there are multiple items, they are listed as *2 off*, *3 off* and so on.

For example it would be similar to this:

My product comprising of:

- 2 off card 1
- 1 off card 2
- 1 off transit case

Is this correct? I thought it should be *2 of*, *3 of* and so on. I would like to know if the usage is correct and if possible why *off* is used in this context.

Comment: Needs more context. Can you cut and paste a couple of lines plus the intro?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. It is a rather idiomatic use. Think *one off*.

Comment: @Mitch it is a standard phrase common in the given context (technical documents).

Comment: Is this American or British, or elsewhere?

Comment: It is British English.

Comment: @Firedragon It is now in AmE as well. See the Ben reference in my answer.

Comment: @TrevorD Its origins may be BrE, but is universally used in technical literature. Generally tech writing does not render itself to BrE or AmE but instead, a common ground, understood almost everywhere.

Comment: @Kris: Your answer talks about 'one-off' as a noun, but I don't yet see that in the OP. That is why I ask for an example in context. A listing with '3 off'? That doesn't yet seem to fit for me.

Comment: @Kris: Ben's article seems to support the fact that it is not well recognized in AmE.

Comment: @Mitch It doesn't seem fit for you because it's not intended to. That construction is used exclusively with a specific meaning in its specific context in technical literature alone. There are several such phrases that make no sense to a language scholar but work in their domains. Think jargon.

Comment: @Kris: It'd be easier to follow this...if I had some context!

Comment: @Mitch One way to look at it is: the batch size. A machine churns out four pieces from 'stock'. You get four items "off" the machine at a time -- a four-off production line! HTH.

Comment: Further note: The 'off' terminology may come from the 'material take-off list', which is the list of all the materials required to build an engineering project. It is commonly used in Commonwealth countries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BEN ZIMMER, On Language **The Origins of ‘One-Off’**:
[The New York Times (Magazine) July 2, 2010](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/07/04/magazine/04FOB-onlanguage-t.html?_r=0)

> … this British usage of ***off*** typically appears with a number to indicate a quantity of items produced in some manufacturing process. The Oxford English Dictionary, … takes this back to a 1934 quotation from the Proceedings of the Institute of British Foundrymen: "A splendid one-off pattern can be swept up in a very little time." Other numbers can fit the bill, as in the O.E.D.'s 1973 example of an advertisement for "Kienzle printers, 6 off, surplus to manufacturing requirements.
>
> "Though some Americans might still find *one-off* annoyingly British-sounding, there's no need to fear it as a solecism. It's a well-manufactured word, even if it feels a little off-kilter. [emphasis mine]

I think that is quite self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That seems to be what is being used here and it is good to know where it has come from.

Comment: Incidentally, Ben explained it pretty well saving us a lot of effort. Thank Ben, not I. :)

Answer (score -1):

Manufacturing lines run X qty of product "off" their line to fill an order. Customer wants 20 wheels? We run 20 wheels off the line... = 20 off.
This ends up on requisitions or PO's as "20 off" and gets adopted outside the original environment where it becomes confusing. EG - engineers who write "columns requires 3 off M20 bolts" etc...